# How can i run a php script on a server every month without running a cron job. e.g. using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, cron

Is it possible to run a `.php` file on the server every month without using a `cron` job. Basicly i need to run a `.php` file every month or given time interval preferably in seconds. I need this to be done automatically every given set of intevals in this case month, the month to seconds or milliseconds is not an issue, the issue is the actual job. this file needs to be automatically opened with no human interaction. For the sake of getting the drift of the functionality i need i can even run the actual code and not the file where ever it may need to be ran. Help greatly appreciated. I will post a solution if i find one before any answer.If however there is no other way of doing this than using `cron` i will then be forced to. Thanks!

Comment: That's exactly what crons are for and there is nothing in PHP or .htaccess which does the same thing. If you have consistent traffic you can setup a virtual cron in PHP that checks the date and runs data like a cron would, but that's overly complicated in comparison.

Comment: What do you have against cron jobs?

Comment: Hi Kerry, i see there are some cron jobs which can get do this every month, writing the script for cron to use based on consistent traffic would be the same as running the php script on the header of your website to check the date and run the script wouldnt it be?

Comment: @putvande nothing, i dont have server access

Comment: @Wandile Get a new host then.  `.htaccess` is just an Apache configuration file, and has absolutely nothing to do with scheduling anything.

Comment: @Wandile the idea behind the virtual cron is that, on every single web access (basically, ALL hits on your site), check to see if the process needs to be run (checking database value, contents of a file, somehow determine the last time the process was run and see if it needs to be run again) then simply execute it during the web request if it needs to be run.  The down sides are that this affects _every web request_, and will cause a massive slowdown during each request that kicks off the job.

Comment: @Brad thanks guys, will do as kerry suggested, but will use only `php` code that checks for the day on the header. Seems i gave `.htaccess` unnecessary super powers.

Comment: @watcher thanks bud. will just use `php` script on header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some web cron service. I'm not going to propose any particular one, just search for `web cron` yourself.

Comment: A web cron service I've used before is https://www.setcronjob.com/ - it works fine and has a free account option. (I'm not affiliated with them.)